# Can not see the imported code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I created a local library and import to another project to use it as following:

[image]

As you can see the library is `kafka-api_2.12-0.1`.

When I want to take a look at code on the `kafka-api_2.12-0.1` library, it shows:
[image]

Not as structured code, but rather in spaghetti code. As you can see, there is a download button, what does it mean?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't work with IntelliJ IDEA but hopefully I can answer your question. What you see is not a real source code but a disassembled class file (please note .class extension in the name of the file you look at).
Hence "Not as structured code, but rather in spaghetti code".
And "Download..." means exactly what it tells, i.e. suggests to download actual source code, i.e. jar containing corresponding .scala file counterpart.